# create tabbed view to display web pages

Tags: android

In my app I am making a web browser in which I want to show different pages in form of tabs. I want to create a view like this

[image]

But I have no idea how to do this. Need guidance regarding the components required.

Answer (score 0):

Well the "simple" way to achieve this would be to create an adapter of some sort that overrides the getView() function to create a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)
and return it as one of the items. The URL of this webview can be mapped to an array or cursor. Since a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) is a very costly component, you will need to implement the [ViewHolder](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) pattern to ensure the webviews are recycled properly.

A lot more work is required to get the rounded corners plus the extra top features but hopefully this can get you started on the right track.